# TCPDF Custom Page number format

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Is it possible in TCPDF to implement a custom page number format? If it is, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change how TCPDF works you need overwrite footer method and implemet your custom logic.

```
class CUSTOMPDF extends TCPDF {
  public function Footer() {

    $this->SetY(-10);
    $this->SetFont('verdana', 'N', 9);
    //more logic, take a look at the parent::Footer method

 }
}
```

use it by calling `$pdf = new CUSTOMPDF(<options>);`

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```

You have to extend TCPDF class as shown in example below:

```
 class MYPDF extends TCPDF {  
       // Page footer
        public function Footer() {
            // Position at 15 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-8);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
            // Page number
          $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');     
        }      
    }


$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->AddPage();
```